# ReactJS and Magento 2: Update Shopping Cart in React?

Tags: magento2, javascript, react-js

I would like to integrate ReactJS as a component in Magento 2 for a custom module. In this module it should be possible to add items to the shopping cart.

How can I trigger Magento in ReactJS to execute Magento_Customer/js/customer-data => customer-data .reload(["cart"], true);

executes?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to include an event trigger outside your React App in Magento which would trigger the behaviour.

```
define([
'jquery', 
'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
], function ($, customerData) {
  'use strict';

  return function () {
      customerData.initStorage();
      customerData.init();
      document.addEventListener('triggerAddToCart', function () {
          const sections = ['cart'];
          customerData.invalidate(sections);
          customerData.reload(sections, false);
      });
  }
});
```

Inside your React app you would then be able to trigger like this:

```
  document.dispatchEvent(new Event('triggerAddToCart'));
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a window function which you can trigger inside react. e.g.

```
window.customCloseModal = function(){modalJquerySelector.modal('closeModal')};
```